# Using 2 ranges to update a cell

Tags: excel, vba

Using 2 ranges; first range has a filtered list of claims, second range has a filtered list of people.  In the 2nd routine, when the 1st person is assigned a claim, the fourth record in the claim range is updated with the person, instead of the first record.  The person's name is "Alonzo Bertha".

Here is the resulting data after updating;

[image: Data results after setting the cell value]

I have tried different combinations of setting tRange, and also referencing PendDataRange directly.

Here are the 2 subroutines that create the ranges from filtered claims and filtered people; CalcTier85Counts filters the claims and assigns the first range.  If there are claims, the sub routine Assign85UsingTierMapping is called to assign the claims to a person.  Assign85UsingTierMapping sets the 2nd range containing the people's names to assign the claims to.

```
Public Sub CalcTier85Counts()
   
    Dim LoopCnt As Long
    
    lastAssignRow = WSTiers.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    lastAssignRow = WSTiers.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row
     lastRow = WSStarting85.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row
   
   '  for each tier, filter the starting85 spreadsheet for the tier, TITLE field, column 12, and the criteria from the Assign85Critiera spreadsheet
   '  The Assign85Criteria spreadsheet identifies the criteria to apply to the Starting 85 spreadsheet. This spreadsheets has the claims.  Variables hold the column number and criteria
   '  and are set in the sub routine Get85Criteria()
   '  After filters are applied, If the number of records > 1, then can start the assignment process
   
    For LoopCnt = 2 To lastAssignRow
        searchValue = Trim$(WSTiers.Range("A" & LoopCnt).Value)
        WSStarting85.Range("A1:EP" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=searchValue
        WSStarting85.Range("A1:EP" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=Assign85CriteriaColumn, Criteria1:=Assign85CriteriaValue  'variables from the assign85criteria spreadsheet
        lastFilterRow = WSStarting85.Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If lastFilterRow > 1 Then
           RowCount = WSStarting85.Range("L1:L" & lastFilterRow).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1
           Set PendDataRange = WSStarting85.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
           WSTiers.Cells(LoopCnt, "B").Value = RowCount
           Call Assign85UsingTierMapping
        Else
           WSTiers.Cells(LoopCnt, "B").Value = 0
        End If
        WSStarting85.ShowAllData
    Next LoopCnt
    
End Sub

Public Sub Assign85UsingTierMapping()
    Dim PerPerson85 As Long
    Dim Remaining85 As Long
    Dim PersonName As String
    Dim PersonMax As Integer
    Dim SkipFirstRow As Boolean
    Dim tFilterRow As Long
    Dim tRowNumber As Long
    Dim tRange As Range
    Dim AssignLoop
    
    SkipFirstRow = True
    WSTierMapping.Range("A1:D" & TierMappingRowCount).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=searchValue    ' searchvalue is the tier from CalcTier85Counts sub routine
    WSTierMapping.Range("A1:D" & TierMappingRowCount).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="N"             ' PTO = N criteria
    
    TierMappingFilterCount = WSTierMapping.Range("B1:B" & TierMappingRowCount).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1
    If TierMappingFilterCount > 1 Then
       PerPerson85 = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown((RowCount / TierMappingFilterCount), 0)
       If PerPerson85 = 0 Then
          PerPerson85 = 1
       End If
       Remaining85 = RowCount
       Set tmpRange = WSTierMapping.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
       tFilterRow = 1
          For Each row1 In tmpRange.Rows
              If SkipFirstRow = False And Remaining85 > 0 Then
                 PersonName = row1.Cells(1).Value
                 PersonMax = row1.Cells(3).Value
                 ' assign the persons name to the claims
                 For AssignLoop = 1 To PerPerson85
                     Set tRange = PendDataRange.Offset(tFilterRow, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)   'go to next record, also skipping past column heading
                     tRange.Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(, 42).Value = PersonName  ' updates 4th filtered record
                     tRange.Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(tFilterRow, 42).Value = PersonName  ' updates 4th filtered record
                     If I > PersonMax Then
                        I = PerPerson85
                     Else
                        Remaining85 = Remaining85 - 1
                        tFilterRow = tFilterRow + 1
                     End If
                 Next AssignLoop
              End If
              SkipFirstRow = False
          Next row1
       

    
    End If
    WSTierMapping.ShowAllData

End Sub
```

Comment: Please share code as text in your post.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. No one can copy/paste it then.